# How to compile with boost library on cluster?

Tags: boost, compilation, static-libraries

I'm trying to compile my program with boost library on cluster. But I don't know how to link the library on my cluster.

I compile my program locally on my mac using this command:

```
mpic++ -o local ods_v2.4.cpp -L/opt/local/lib/  -lboost_iostreams-mt -lz -I/opt/local/include
```

This is the information of boost on my cluster:

```
-bash-4.1$ module avail boost

---------------------------------------------------------------- /opt/modules/modulefiles -----------------------------------------------------------------
boost/1.49.0_intel-12.0.084   boost/1.49.0_intel-13.0.1.117
-bash-4.1$ module show boost
-------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/modules/modulefiles/boost/1.49.0_intel-13.0.1.117:

module-whatis    access boost ver. 1.49.0 header files and libraries 
module       load python/2.7.3_intel-13.0.1.117 
setenv       BOOST_HOME /apps/rhel6/boost/1.49.0_intel-13.0.1.117 
setenv       BOOST_ROOT /apps/rhel6/boost/1.49.0_intel-13.0.1.117 
setenv       BOOST_INCLUDE -I/apps/rhel6/boost/1.49.0_intel-13.0.1.117/include 
setenv       LINK_BOOST -L/apps/rhel6/boost/1.49.0_intel-13.0.1.117/lib -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /apps/rhel6/boost/1.49.0_intel-13.0.1.117/lib 
prepend-path     LD_LIBRARY_PATH /apps/rhel6/boost/1.49.0_intel-13.0.1.117/lib 
-------------------------------------------------------------------

-bash-4.1$
```

I wonder what command line should I use?
I'm trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
-bash-4.1$ mpiCC -o cluster ods_v2.4.cpp  $LINK_BOOST $BOOST_INCLUDE -lz
```

Answer (score 1):

It is solved

```
-bash-4.1$ mpiCC -o cluster ods_v2.4.cpp  $LINK_BOOST -lboost_iostreams -lz $BOOST_INCLUDE
```

I forgot the-lbookst-XXXX

Thanks